# jsf +richfaces popup window not displayed

Tags: jsf, richfaces

```
<richdatatable>
<a4j:commandLink styleClass="addLink"  action="#{depotOpeningStockManageBean.createNewLotShow}"
                             execute="@this" oncomplete="#{rich:component('addPane')}.show()"  value="Create" >

                            </a4j:commandLink></richdatatable>

 <rich:popupPanel id="addPane" resizeable="true"  domElementAttachment="parent">     
             <h:commandLink  value="cancel"  onclick="#{rich:component('addPane')}.hide()" />
             </rich:popupPanel>
```

Why is the popup displayed on richdataGrid and richpanel but not in richDatatable?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is the problem or error you have?

Comment: Question is not clear. According to the given sample you are using the tag as `<richdatatable>` Change it as `<rich:dataTable>`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot the column definition:

```
<rich:dataTable ... >
    <rich:column ... >
        <a4j:commandLink ... />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

And you have to provide a list to the table. If you only want a `<table>` rendered then the `<h:panelGrid>` is the tag you are looking for.